# (MapServer Osm) Map Accessibility

Tags: openlayers-2, mapserver, security

I have a tile server (MapCache) with a personalized map.

For client side's rendering I use OpenLayers.

I'd like my personalized cache to be accessible only on my web site,
i.e. I don't want another website to use the mapcache on my MapCache server.

Is there any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using apache for serving your tiles, try to check out [Password Protect a Directory with .htaccess](http://www.addedbytes.com/blog/code/password-protect-a-directory-with-htaccess/). it is all about retricting access to a directory on a web server using .htaccess.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess

> A .htaccess (hypertext access) file is a directory-level configuration
>   file supported by several web servers, that allows for decentralized
>   management of web server configuration. They are placed inside the web
>   tree, and are able to override a subset of the server's global
>   configuration for the directory that they are in, and all
>   sub-directories.
>
> The original purpose of .htaccess—reflected in its name—was to allow
>   per-directory access control, by for example requiring a password to
>   access the content. Nowadays however, the .htaccess files can override
>   many other configuration settings including content type and character
>   set, CGI handlers, etc.

i hope it helps you...